# Hibernate StackOverflowError when fetching data from @ManyToMany releationship and there is more than one elemnet in table

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to solve issue StackOverflowError when fetching data from table. When in table Employee is one employee everything works fine. But when there is more than one element i got stack overflow when I'm tring to access Employee Set form table Outpost. Here is my code

**Employees**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employees")
public class EmployeeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Employee_Outpost", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "outpost_id") })
    private Set<OutpostEntity> outposts =  new HashSet<OutpostEntity>(); 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ShipperEntity> shippers = new HashSet<ShipperEntity>();
```

**Outpost**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Outpost")
public class OutpostEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7782359215536098452L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "outpost_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer outpostID;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "outpost", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ShipperEntity> shippers = new HashSet<ShipperEntity>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "outposts", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<EmployeeEntity> employees = new HashSet<EmployeeEntity>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "outpost", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AreaEntity> areas = new HashSet<AreaEntity>();
```

**StackOverflowError**

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{orderFormBean.submit}: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseResourceImpl.execute(BridgePhaseResourceImpl.java:103)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:128)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.serveResource(GenericFacesPortlet.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:82)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:601)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:696)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.serveResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:462)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doServeResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:792)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.serveResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:152)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.serveResource(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.serveResource(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.serveResource(PortletContainerUtil.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:364)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{orderFormBean.submit}: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 134 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    ... 138 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.values(HashMap.java:1036)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.LoadQueryInfluencers.getEnabledFilters(LoadQueryInfluencers.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.processFilters(QueryParameters.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1827)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2238)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:428)
    at pl.imsi.domain.OutpostEntity.hashCode(OutpostEntity.java:184)
    at pl.imsi.domain.AreaEntity.hashCode(AreaEntity.java:85)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:366)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:496)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
```

hashCode() & equals()

```
    @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((employeeId == null) ? 0 : employeeId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((liferayUserId == null) ? 0 : liferayUserId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((outposts == null) ? 0 : outposts.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((phone == null) ? 0 : phone.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((shippers == null) ? 0 : shippers.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((sureName == null) ? 0 : sureName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    EmployeeEntity other = (EmployeeEntity) obj;
    if (email == null) {
        if (other.email != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
        return false;
    if (employeeId == null) {
        if (other.employeeId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!employeeId.equals(other.employeeId))
        return false;
    if (liferayUserId == null) {
        if (other.liferayUserId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!liferayUserId.equals(other.liferayUserId))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (outposts == null) {
        if (other.outposts != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!outposts.equals(other.outposts))
        return false;
    if (phone == null) {
        if (other.phone != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!phone.equals(other.phone))
        return false;
    if (shippers == null) {
        if (other.shippers != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!shippers.equals(other.shippers))
        return false;
    if (sureName == null) {
        if (other.sureName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!sureName.equals(other.sureName))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I find solutions, I deleted override methods hashCode & equals and now works fine.

Comment: You probably had a cyclic reference in getHashCode and/or equals.

Comment: Could somebody explain me what was exacly wrong with override methods?

Comment: if (obj == null)
        return false;
when comparing a employe refrence to null with null this should output true, in your case it ouputs false.
check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)